# Where can I find AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard connection string?

Tags: function, azure, triggers, cosmos

I created an Azure function in Visual studio 2017 with Cosmos DB Trigger. In local.setting.json it asks me for three things and I am puzzled about the first two.

**AzureWebJobsStorage** and **AzureWebJobsDashboard**

Where do I find these two? 
I have been watching some tutorial videos and it seems a little bit difficult to know which information I should rely on. 
In one video, one has shown that I go to my Portal/FunctionApp/MyFunction/ApplicationSetting and there I can find them. I have tried that and I only could find **AzureWebJobsStorage**
Another has shown that I can go to my Portal/StorageAccount/MyStorage/AccessKeys and I only can see the information that are in the picture I have attached.
In that video I saw that the guy used the exact same key for both of these properties(or whatever they are called) which none of them ended with **EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net** and my both keys in the picture end with this phrase.

1. I hope I make sense about what I am looking for.
2. I also hope someone can help me to know which is which and why there is **EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net** at the end of my keys, and if there should be, and are these two keys the same?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.Yes, the picture(Connection string) you attached is the value for AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard

2.EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net, it's a path means that the blob / queue etc. path on azure storage, cause some queue/blob triggers in the azure function or some logs will stored in the blob. Details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings).

There are 2 keys there, it's just for backup / security reason. If one of your key is exposed, you can use another key. More details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-manage?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#access-keys).